# Let T be a linear operator on an inner product space V. Let $U_1=T+T^{*}$ and $U_2=T T^{*}$. Prove $U_1=U_1^{*}$ and $U_2=U_2^{*}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let T be a linear operator on an inner product space V. Let $U_1=T+T^{*}$ and $U_2=T T^{*}$. Prove $U_1=U_1^{*}$ and $U_2=U_2^{*}$

How am I supposed to prove this? This doesn't tell it's finite-dimensional.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm pretty sure the exercise intended $V$ to be finite-dimensional. Infinite-dimensional inner product spaces may be "incomplete", in which case the adjoint becomes a little trickier to work with (to the point where $T + T^*$ doesn't obviously make sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following: $(A+B)^{*}=A^{*}+B^{^*}$, $(AB)^{*}=B^{*}A^{*}$ and $A^{**}=A$.